# how to get the cell value of a selected cell from Table view in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6

Am displaying images in a table view controller where the images are rendered from the URL as XML file. It works well with listing images as scroll view. Now i want to select a particular image and the window should show the selected Cell images alone. For this do i need to get the Cell value. If so how can i get the particular cell value and display its corresponding images as a collection view in next window.

Kindly suggest me an idea. For your better understanding i pasted below an image how my storyboard currently looks and how i need an output.
[image: Storyboard and output]

Hope you understand my problem.

Comment: What do you need from the cell? The row index? The text value?

Comment: sorry as am new to iphone development i dont know exactly which gives me a reference to next window that displays the particular images related to the cell. For your understanding if i have 3 cells (cell-1, cell-2, cell-3) with different images, by selecting cell-1 i need to display the images related to that particular cell as collection views.

Comment: An answer has been posted below! You get the row index by the delegate method `-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

You can for example pass the row index to the next view controller and treat this information there!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
// here we get the cell from the selected row.
          UITableViewCell *selectedCell=[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]; 

// perform required operation
         UIImage * image =selectedCell.image;

// use the image in the next window using view controller instance of that view.
}
```

Comment: vinu can you tell me how this image can be related to the next view controller

Comment: first you need to create instance of that view controller.
then set the UIimageview of that viewcontroller to the selected image.

Comment: Example;
// create instance 
nextViewController *nextView =[[nextViewController alloc]init];

// set uiimageview property in that view with the selected image
nextView.imageDisplayer =selectedCell.image;

//Display the viewController and set that image when view is loaded

Comment: k but in this how am getting the selected image `image` from this `UIImage * image =selectedCell.image;` line on the nextviewcontroller

Comment: you are creating and calling the instance on the same function written above. so image is got already

Comment: Got somewhat can you say am right here,                `UITableViewCell *selectedCell=[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];`
      `UIImage * image =selectedCell.image;`
      `nextviewcontroller *next = [[nextviewcontroller alloc] initWithNibName:@"detail" bundle:nil];`
      `[self.navigationController pushViewController:next animated:YES];`

Comment: Before pushing the nextView. u need to store that image so that u can display it in the nextview. So for that u need to create a property in the nextview for uiimage.

Comment: `UIImageView getImage;` `getImage.image = image;` am i right vinu

Answer (score 2):

You should use UITableViewDelegate

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

indexPath will return you number of section and number of row of selected row.

```
indexPath.section;
indexPath.row
```

I hope it was clear. For further understanding you may refer to following tutorials:
http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/using-iphone-tableview-for-displaying-data/
http://www.raywenderlich.com/1797/how-to-create-a-simple-iphone-app-tutorial-part-1

Answer (score 1):

In this case I think you should maintain id for each image on the row. It could be your row number, if you have one image per row. Then from

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

you can pass the id to the next view controller. 
In this view controller you should use this id to get the required data to create your collection view.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank's for your reply. Am not understanding how to pass the id and get the id for each cell.

Comment: I am assuming that you have 1 image per row. So you can assign the image's tag as indexPath.row.. and you can have a variable in the next viewController which you can assign this row number. Now in the viewDidLoad method of next view controller, check the row number and fetch data based on that.

Comment: ya i got somewhat an idea. can i get any reference links related to this.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any link right now. But, it should be pretty simple to implement now by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

For me this is working..

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    customerVC = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil]instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"customerInfoView"];

    customerVC.selectedText = cell.textLabel.text;
    //customerVC is destination viewController instance)

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:customerVC animated:YES]; 
}
```

And in your destination view controller header file just declare a string like

```
@property NSString *selectedText;
```

In viewcontroller.m assign the value like

```
self.selectedBiller.text = self.selectedText;
```

(selectedBiller is a label here)